# Android code inspection is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, lint

It is giving me hundreds of errors which cannot be true, such as 277 Unused declarations, such as the one selected below, which has 36 usages:
[image: code inspector screenshot]

I trusted it to remove some code, and it removed used xml drawables, dimensions...

I tried invalidating cache, reinstalling android studio, nothing does the trick. What could this be?

Comment: This is still the case in Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2. Function parameters are marked as unused even though they are used literally 2 lines down, methods are marked as unused even though Find Usage finds dozens of references, getters are marked as "function return type can be void", fragment layouts marked as unused even though they are used...etc.  That is sad -.-